# How do I POST a new node using the Services module and uuid?

Tags: services

I tried several ways to POST a new node to a Drupal site, but I have failed.

I have installed and configured the **[Services 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)** module (D7) with **[UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid)**, and created a service end point at services.

**I am able to login and i have access token**

I am posting my node json

```
{"type":"article","title":"Test1","language":"und"}
```

on

localhost/drupal/services/node

But its showing " 404 Not found : Could not find the controller."

Comment: Have you enabled the `Node Create` resource at `admin/structure/services/list/[my-endpoint-name]/resources`?

Comment: Yes, because i am using my development instance so i enabled all resource including Node Create